# link to specific item in pagination in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

Here is what I am trying to do..

I am making a "gallery" site for a artist friend of mine and what she wants is all her pictures shown on screen, however once you click on a single picture she wants it to go to just that picture and  to have a "next" and "back" arrows to goto the next picture. she does not want to use lightbox etc.. I know how to make the pagination work , however, what i want to do is if they select a specific picture out of the "show all pictures (thumbnails)" scrreen that it will produce "next" and "prev" and pick up the order that the pagination has already. any suggestions?

Comment: What pagination are you using a library, or with limit or something else

Answer (score 0):

You can assign pagination number. I mean let suppose a user is on page one. Attach 1 with all thumbnails in some way to recognize. Then when user clicks on the thumbnail get the number and put it to pagination code as a page number for query to fetch results. This will not effect other things and every thing will go smoothly.

Comment: is there a way to generate the pagination links for each item on the initial gallery screen( where all thumbnails are shown ) and make the a link to the pagination page that the image corresponds to (limit of 1) so that next and prev will refer to the correct items in line?